# Removing dropdown item from .aspx at pageload

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code that removes the item selected in dropdown1 from dropdown2 when a value in dropdown1 is selected:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList2.Items.Remove(DropDownList1.SelectedItem);

    }
```

that works fine.  However I tried adding the same code at pageload but it's not removing the value I'm guessing because nothing has been selected how can I accomplish this?

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DropDownList2.Items.Remove(DropDownList1.SelectedItem);
    }
```

This is what is not working, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing?

```
if(!IsPostback)
{
    DropDownList2.Items.Remove(DropDownList1.SelectedItem);
}
```

In your `Page_Load` event? Also, how are you binding the data? Why not do this on `Selected_IndexChanged` of the appropriate `DropdowsList` instead of `Page_Load`? It seems to me that that's where this piece of code belongs.

Comment: thats where I have it.  But there there is no indexchanged when the page loads so I have two dropdowns with the same value until I change the first one.

Comment: Then why not removing this item **before** you bind the data to the second dropdown (DropDownList2)? You can easily find the duplicate rows and remove them.

Comment: the dropdowns have the same datasource.  So I don't think I have a way of removing duplicates since they are all duplicates.  What I want to do is on dropdown2 not show what is currently selected in dropdown1.  Which is just figured out keeps removing items, unless I refresh because of the post back :(

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is on dropdown2 not show what is currently selected in dropdown1.

What your problem is, on Page Load everything "resets" back. So DropDownList1.SelectedItem is whatever the first or default item in the list. If DropDownList1.SelectedItem is "One", that it will always remove "One" from DropDownList2.

What you need is a button or a OnSelectedIndexChanged event for your DropDownList1.

Try what I have done below, it worked for me.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOne" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOne_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTwo" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btRemove" runat="server" Text="Remove" 
        onclick="btRemove_Click" />
</div>
</form>
```

---

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // Bind data
            BindLists();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes whatever Selected Item from ddlTwo that is 
    /// currently selected in ddlOne.
    /// </summary>
    private void RemoveFromTwoWhatIsSelectedInOne()
    {
        ddlTwo.Items.Remove(ddlOne.SelectedItem);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Click handler for btRemove. Calls the method 
    /// RemoveFromTwoWhatIsSelectedInOne()
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void btRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RemoveFromTwoWhatIsSelectedInOne();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// OnSelectedIndexChanged handler for ddlOne. Calls the method 
    /// RemoveFromTwoWhatIsSelectedInOne()
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void ddlOne_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RemoveFromTwoWhatIsSelectedInOne();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Binds a list of names the two Drop Down Lists, ddlOne and ddlTwo, by using 
    /// the same Data Source from the Manager.
    /// </summary>
    private void BindLists()
    {
        // Get the data
        Manager theManager = new Manager();
        List<Names> theNames = theManager.GetNames();

        // Assign the data source
        ddlOne.DataSource = theNames;
        ddlTwo.DataSource = theNames;

        // Bind each drop down list
        ddlOne.DataBind();
        ddlTwo.DataBind();
    }
```